# How to check if a puzzle is solved using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want know how to figure out if the puzzle is solved.

I am creating an app for creating custom 6-piece puzzle.

Here's the code:

```
 function approved(){
// Get the canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Load the image
var img = new Image();
img.src = document.getElementById('puzzleprieview').src;

img.onload = function() {
    // Set the canvas size
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Draw the image on the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Split the image into parts
    var w = img.width / 3;
    var h = img.height / 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var x = (i % 3) * w;
        var y = Math.floor(i / 3) * h;

        // Create a new canvas for each part
        var partCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          
     partCanvas.draggable="true";
     
     partCanvas.className="sampcanvas"
$(".sampcanvas").draggable({snap: true});
 
        partCanvas.width = w;
        partCanvas.height = h;
        var partCtx = partCanvas.getContext("2d");

        // Draw the part of the image on the new canvas
        partCtx.drawImage(canvas, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
var number=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        // Do something with each part, such as append it to the document
     const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
      partCanvas.style.left= getRandom(0, 300 - 200)+'px'; //  Horizontally
   partCanvas.style.top = getRandom(0, 300 - 200)+'px'; //  Vertically
        document.getElementById('pieces').appendChild(partCanvas);
    }
}

}
```

That code is used to create puzzle pieces and append them.

What I need to do is somehow compare the puzzle piece solving to the canvas that is created

Comment: Fiddle for total code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Kw1xOjMrRs

Comment: So you got a warning not to post JSFiddle links. Why not heed that warning click [edit] then `[<>]` and post the [mcve] here? We do not need the doctype and head information so make the code as small as possible to show the issue

Comment: Also only have ONE pixi link - no need (and not a great idea) to load BOTH the minified and the full version of the same library

Comment: This is also a bad idea: `<script src="file:///home/chronos/u-768f0652691b614fec413d1049dad9cc29d55a34/MyFiles/html/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, great task in general and question in particular !

To achieve this purpose you could, f.e. put into each puzzlePart block it's initial position using "data-" attributes:

```
    var x = (i % 3) * w;
    var y = Math.floor(i / 3) * h;

    // Create a new canvas for each part
    let partCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    partCanvas.dataset.xx = x;
    partCanvas.dataset.yy = y;
```

Next, whenever needed, you are able to compare current position of puzzle parts with their initial ones. I took initial position from .dataset and current using .getBoundingClientRect():

```
        var canvasOffsets = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        var elementScreenOffsets = partCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        var elementOffsets = {
            x: elementScreenOffsets.left - canvasOffsets.left,
            y: elementScreenOffsets.top - canvasOffsets.top,
        };

        var initialOffsets = {
            x: partCanvas.dataset.xx,
            y: partCanvas.dataset.yy,
        };
```

As an option, you could for example "freeze" puzzle parts on the screen when they're moreless in their initial position:

```
        var FREEZE_DISTASNCE = 30;
        if (
            Math.abs(elementOffsets.x - initialOffsets.x) <
                FREEZE_DISTASNCE &&
            Math.abs(elementOffsets.y - initialOffsets.y) <
                FREEZE_DISTASNCE
        ) {
            makeNotDraggable(partCanvas);
            partCanvas.style.left = partCanvas.dataset.xx;
            partCanvas.style.top = partCanvas.dataset.yy;
            partCanvas.style.zIndex = -1;
        }
```

So eventually I decided to modify initial question's code to make it fully working using my ideas above. Plus I decided to implement this POC with "generic" image which you could pick

For drag-n-drop implementation I referenced this article: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

File inputs Api: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file

```js
document
    .querySelector('.js-puzzle-image')
    .addEventListener('change', function () {
        document.querySelector('.js-puzzle-image').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('#pieces').style.display = 'inline-block';

        var imageSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

        approved(imageSrc);
    });

function approved(imageSrc) {
    const el_wrap = document.querySelector('#pieces');

    // Get the canvas and context
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Load the image
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSrc;

    img.onload = function () {
        // Set the canvas size
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        el_wrap.style.width = `${img.width}px`;
        el_wrap.style.height = `${img.height}px`;

        // Draw the image on the canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Split the image into parts
        var w = img.width / 3;
        var h = img.height / 2;
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            var x = (i % 3) * w;
            var y = Math.floor(i / 3) * h;

            // Create a new canvas for each part
            let partCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            partCanvas.dataset.xx = x;
            partCanvas.dataset.yy = y;

            partCanvas.draggable = 'true';

            partCanvas.className = 'sampcanvas';
            //$('.sampcanvas').draggable({ snap: true });

            partCanvas.width = w;
            partCanvas.height = h;
            var partCtx = partCanvas.getContext('2d');

            // Draw the part of the image on the new canvas
            partCtx.drawImage(canvas, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
            // Do something with each part, such as append it to the document
            const getRandom = (min, max) =>
                Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            partCanvas.style.left = getRandom(0, img.width - w) + 'px'; //  Horizontally
            partCanvas.style.top = getRandom(0, img.height - h) + 'px'; //  Vertically

            document.getElementById('pieces').appendChild(partCanvas);

            // making elements "draggable", but "freeze" them when they're on the correct position
            makeDraggable(partCanvas, () => {
                var canvasOffsets = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                var elementScreenOffsets = partCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                var elementOffsets = {
                    x: elementScreenOffsets.left - canvasOffsets.left,
                    y: elementScreenOffsets.top - canvasOffsets.top,
                };

                var initialOffsets = {
                    x: partCanvas.dataset.xx,
                    y: partCanvas.dataset.yy,
                };

                var FREEZE_DISTASNCE = 30;
                if (
                    Math.abs(elementOffsets.x - initialOffsets.x) <
                        FREEZE_DISTASNCE &&
                    Math.abs(elementOffsets.y - initialOffsets.y) <
                        FREEZE_DISTASNCE
                ) {
                    makeNotDraggable(partCanvas);
                    partCanvas.style.left = partCanvas.dataset.xx + 'px';
                    partCanvas.style.top = partCanvas.dataset.yy + 'px';
                    partCanvas.style.zIndex = -1;
                }
            });
        }

        canvas.style.display = 'none';
    };
}

// https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp
var zIndexTracker = 0;

function makeNotDraggable(elmnt) {
    elmnt.onmousedown = undefined;
}

function makeDraggable(elmnt, onDrop) {
    var pos1 = 0,
        pos2 = 0,
        pos3 = 0,
        pos4 = 0;
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;

        elmnt.style.zIndex = ++zIndexTracker;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2 + 'px';
        elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1 + 'px';
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        // stop moving when mouse button is released:
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
        onDrop();
    }
}
```

```css
#pieces {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sampcanvas {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
        <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" class="js-puzzle-image" />

        <div id="pieces" style="display: none">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
```

Of course, this code snippet is "not ideal" from code quality perspective and should be re-worked to be more object-oriented, to have better code responsibility splitting, etc... But for demostration purposes, I believe, that's a good start

Comment: Distance. So where is the "You did it!"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
  partCanvas.dataset.index = i;
```

and then you can in your drop function do something like this

```
const finished = () => { 
  const indexes = document.querySelectorAll('.sampcanvas')
  .map(imgPart => imgPart.dataset.index)
  .join('');
  console.log(indexes);
  return indexes ===  '0123456';
}
```

Comment: It throws an error: Can't set properties of undefined

Comment: Needs to be improved.

Comment: spelling mistake `dataset`, anyway you got another solution - it was as good as I could come up with with the lack of drag/drop code